# Let $\alpha \neq \beta$ be the roots of $x^2 + ax + b \in\Bbb R[x]$. Prove $\exists c \in \Bbb R$ such that $\alpha-\beta=c$ or $\alpha-\beta=ci$.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Just a heads up: "$a$" and "$α$" are different

Let $a,b \in \Bbb R$ and suppose $a^2 − 4b \neq 0$. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the (distinct) roots of the polynomial $x^2 + ax + b$. Prove that there is a real number $c$ such that either $\alpha − \beta = c$ or
$\alpha − \beta = ci$.

I have no idea how to prove this mathematically. Can someone explain how they would this, including how they would implement this using a proof tree?

This is what I was trying to do.

$$(x - \alpha)(x - \beta) = x^2 + ax + b$$

$$x^2 - \alpha x - \beta x + \alpha \beta = x^2 + ax + b$$

$$-\alpha x - \beta x = ax$$

$$-x(\alpha + \beta) = ax$$

$$(\alpha + \beta) = -a$$

$$\alpha \beta = b$$

However, I'm confused where to go from here and wondering if what I'm doing is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $a^2 - 4 b > 0$ then the roots are :
   $$\alpha = \dfrac{-a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4 b}}{2} \text{ and } \beta = \dfrac{-a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4 b}}{2}$$
   so :
   $$\alpha - \beta = \sqrt{a^2 - 4 b}$$ 
   Let $c = \sqrt{a^2 - 4 b}$ then $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha - \beta = c$.
2. If $a^2 - 4 b < 0$ then the roots are :
   $$\alpha = \dfrac{-a + i \sqrt{4b - a^2}}{2} \text{ and } \beta = \dfrac{-a - i \sqrt{4 b - a^2}}{2}$$
   so :
   $$\alpha - \beta = i \sqrt{4 b - a^2}$$ 
   Let $c = \sqrt{4 b - a^2}$ then $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha - \beta = i c$.

Comment: I think your last line is backwards:  $c = \sqrt{4b-a^2}$ is real.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of factoring, you can apply the formula for the quadratic equation directly.

If $Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0$, then the two roots are given by

$$\frac{1}{2A} \left[-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}\right].$$

This means that (when the roots are distinct), the difference in the two roots will be

$$\frac{1}{2A} \times 2 \times \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC} ~: ~B^2 - 4AC \neq 0.$$

In your problem, you have :

- $A = 1.$
- $B = a.$
- $C = b.$

So, the difference in the two roots is

$$\pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}. \tag1 $$

The expression in (1) above will either be real or imaginary, depending on whether $(a^2 - 4b)$ is positive or negative.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How do you calculate A, B, C?

Comment: @CodingKook $$Ax^2 + Bx + C = x^2 + ax + b \implies A=1, ~B = a, ~C = b.$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get it now

Answer (score 1):

Solving the equation $x^2+ax+b=0$, we have $$x=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2},$$
or more specifically, wlog, we can write $$
\alpha=\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2},\quad \beta=\frac{-a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}.$$
The difference, $\alpha-\beta$, can then be simplified:  $$\alpha-\beta=\sqrt{a^2-4b}.$$

We are given $a^2-4b\neq0$, and this leads into two cases:
If $a^2-4b>0$, then $\alpha-\beta=c$ (the square root of a positive number is a real number).
If $a^2-4b<0$, then $\alpha-\beta=ci$ (the square root of a negative number is an imaginary number).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. How do you know that the roots are -a + sqrt(a^2 - 4b)/2 and -a - sqrt(a^2 - 4b)/2 and not both -a + sqrt(a^2 - 4b)/2?

Comment: We are given $a^2-4b\neq0.$

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that needs very little algebra.

If the roots are real their difference $c$ is real.

If the roots are complex they are conjugates, so their difference is a real multiple of $i$.